# What is the best way to write flowtype definitions for private modules?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, flow-typed

1. What is the best way to write flowtype definitions for a module?
   I am aware of the [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed) project, is this the best way to write definitions even if you own the library? The [documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/) is not very clear about this.
2. flow-typed approach does not work for private modules. What is the recommendation in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend reading through [Authoring and publishing JavaScript modules with Flow](https://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2017/01/npm-flowjs-javascript/).

The short answer is that you can distribute your module with `.js.flow` files that Flow will read to get type information. Usually these are just copies of your original source code from before the type annotations were deleted, created using the `flow-copy-source` package.

`flow-typed` exists to provide definitions for modules that do not provide them automatically, but you can include the type definitions right inside your own modules.